# character vector to string (with quotes and comma) using R

Tags: mysql, r

Hi when I do `paste(c("A","B","C"),collapse='","')`,
the output is `"A\",\"B\",\"C"`.

How can I get `"A","B","C"` as one string?

Answer (score 3):

Even though R will output `"A\",\"B\",\"C"`,
keep in mind that the actual value is really `A","B","C`.
You can verify this by printing the value:

```
> cat(paste(c("A","B","C"),collapse='","'))
A","B","C
```

Now, if you want the value to be `"A","B","C"` instead of `A","B","C`,
then you need to `paste` one more time, to prepend a `"` and append a `"`:

```
> cat(paste('"', paste(c("A","B","C"),collapse='","'), '"', sep=''))
"A","B","C"
```